# What regular expression can I use to replace @Url.Content("~/path/to/resource") with "~/path/to/resource"

Tags: visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've upgraded yet another MVC 3 project to MVC 4 and I'm getting tired of replacing `<link>` href and `<script>` src values with their `@Url.Content()`-less values. (MVC 4 Razor 2 will automagically resolve content paths for any value beginning with `~/`).

What regular expression can I use in visual studio to replace them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find what:**

`"\@Url\.Content\({:q}\)"`

**Replace with:**

`\1`

Make sure **Use** is checked and **Regular expressions** is selected.